Getting type error trying to create a Vol Tag in AWS via Lambda
I have a AWS Lambda to add/update the tags on an EBS volume.  This is using python3. Here is some of my code:
def ApplyAllEc2tag(aws_client, instanceid, resourceid, mountpoint, instanceName):
    ec2 = aws_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceid])
    instances = ec2['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
    newInstanceName = "VOL::" + instanceName + "::_" + mountpoint
    tags = instances['Tags']
    for tag in tags:
        if "aws:" in tag['Key']:
            del tag['Key']
            del tag['Value']
            continue
        ec2 = aws_client.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=[resourceid])
        ec2 = aws_client.create_tags(Resources=[resourceid], Tags=[
                                     {'Key': tag['Key'], 'Value': tag['Value']}])
    
    # Create the name tag which will overwrite the tag it if exists or create it if it does not.
    ec2=aws_client.create_tags(Resources=[resourceid], Tags=[
                               {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': newInstanceName}])

This all works fine as long as the instance has a Name tag.  If the instance does not have the Name tag then I get this error:
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "can only concatenate str (not \"dict\") to str",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "51e190b0-4534-469f-93c0-9138d0dc8c64",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 16, in ApplyAllEc2tag\n    newInstanceName = \"VOL::\" + instanceName + \"::_\" + mountpoint\n"
  ]
}

I understand newInstanceName is a string but why is it only failing when the Tag needs to be created and not overwritten?  How can I fix this?

This problem is caused by other code, not this function - post everything from handler to the call site. instanceName is likely found by looping over instance tags, and the flaw is somewhere there. Note how you needlessly overwrite ec2 variables here - something like this in another function may cause such problems.
